# <location> path attribute must be a relative virtual path: Location starts with "."

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-express

I need to set custom web.config settings for a location that starts with a ".":

```
<location path=".somepath">
```

Unfortunately, ASP.NET doesn't seem to like  paths that start with periods. I get the following error:

> Configuration Error: `<location> path attribute must be a relative virtual path.  It cannot start with any of ' ' '.' '/' or '\'.`

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a pretty easy solution: put a web.config file in the actually directory that starts with a ".". So instead of using the root web.config with `<location path=".somepath">`, I simply created a web.config file in the ".somepath" directory and added the configuration there. If ".somepath" were a file, I'm not sure what I would've done.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the path with "~/" thus:

```
<location path="~/.somepath">
```